# express POST req.body parser is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I saw similar issues on Stack Overflow and found solution to use of:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

But while printing log `req.body` is blank.

app.js contents:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Define the port to run on
app.set('port', 8888);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/webapp/public')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/getsolution', function (req, res) {
    console.log("request body is",req.body); //----req.body is blank here
});
```

Post request code from angular is as below

```
var parameters = JSON.stringify({ "urlPath": $location.path()});
$http.post('http://localhost:8888/getsolution/', parameters)
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response.data == "") {
            $window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8888/';
        } else {
            $scope.puzzle = response.data;
            $scope.puzzleSolution = response.data.solution;
        }
    }).catch(function onError(response) {
    $window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8888/';
});
```

Log printing on console is

> request body is {}

### When using with below snippet it is not working

```
var app = angular.module('puzzleappsolution', [], function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 });//----->It is now working
```

### But when using below it is working

```
var app = angular.module('puzzleappsolution', []);
```

Comment: @Sam thanks for proper indenting

Comment: have you tried including bodyparser.raw?

Comment: @JefreeSujit Tried this but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Content-Type` header to your request in angular:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8888/getsolution/', parameters, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea what else can be wrong. I run your code locally and it works. I only had to add `app.listen(8888)` in order to start the server but I guess you just stripped it out from your code snippet.

Comment: I updated my question and added few lines. Please help me why it is behaving differently in both scenarios. I also want to use $locationProvider variable to get location path.

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue why `$locationProvider` changes the behavior of $http.